# Youtube web scraping by selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, video, youtube

```
Reviews =pd.DataFrame()
k=1
controls > div.ytp-left-controls > a.ytp-next-button.ytp-button')
for i in range(10):
    
    for l in range(k):
        
        for j in range(k):
            
            all_posts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="container"]/h1/yt-formatted-string')
            all_posts = [x.text for x in all_posts]
            posts = pd.Series(all_posts)
            
            all_views = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='short-view-count style-scope ytd-video-view-count-renderer']")
            all_views = [x.text for x in all_views]
            views = pd.Series(all_views)
            
            all_likes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-watch-flexy/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[8]/div[2]/ytd-video-primary-info-renderer/div/div/div[3]/div/ytd-menu-renderer/div/ytd-toggle-button-renderer[1]/a/yt-formatted-string')
            all_likes = [x.text for x in all_likes]
            likes = pd.Series(all_likes)
            
            all_dislikes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-watch-flexy/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[8]/div[2]/ytd-video-primary-info-renderer/div/div/div[3]/div/ytd-menu-renderer/div/ytd-toggle-button-renderer[2]/a/yt-formatted-string')
            all_dislikes = [x.text for x in all_dislikes]
            dislikes = pd.Series(all_dislikes)
            
            all_comments = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-watch-flexy/div[5]/div[1]/div/ytd-comments/ytd-item-section-renderer/div[1]/ytd-comments-header-renderer/div[1]/h2/yt-formatted-string/span[1]')
            all_comments = [x.text for x in all_comments]
            comments = pd.Series(all_comments)
            
            df = pd.DataFrame({"Title":posts, "Views":views, "Likes":likes, "Dislikes":dislikes, "No of Comments":comments})
            
        Reviews = Reviews.append(df) 
        time.sleep(3)
    
    
    next= driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#movie_player > div.ytp-chrome-bottom > div.ytp-chrome-
    next.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    
Reviews
```

Trying to scrape the data like title of video, no. of likes and dislikes, no. of . comments, total views on a video from YouTube particular channel

So I decided to click the play_all button from channel in order to play all the video in a row

But the next play button should be on loop in order to play next next video every time the scraping is done from a particular video

But The next play button loop is not working every time loop start the YouTube next button doesn't work in this code the next play button is denoted by keyword (next)

I am trying the next.click() everything is working fine but the next click is not working as per the loop should goo and the next.click() shows error

Comment: Check if the this line works- `next= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='Next (SHIFT+n)']")

Comment: sometimes it is working with the ("//a[@title='Next (SHIFT+n)']")
but sometimes it shows an error of
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@title='Next (SHIFT+n)']"}
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.131)

Comment: Apply waits. Implicit or explicit, but not both.

Comment: applied but
it didn't worked

Comment: Well I have tired to do similar kind of task. It has worked so far.